# Cookie in laravel

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-8, php-curl

I have an API request using cookie. But I got error expired due to cookie.  I have checked my cookie in inspect element. I have set it correctly. But still go the same error. My question is, is it correct how I send cookie using header like the code below? I'm using laravel-8.

[image: cookie in network]

```
public function step2(Request $request){
    $cookie = Cookie::get('husna');
    $value = $request->session()->get('accessToken');

    $postField = $request->input();
    $formData = $postField['form'];
    
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => ''.$this->api_url.'/deposit?version=1.0.0',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
        "form": '.json_encode($formData).'
    }',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'accept: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$value.'',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Cookie: ' . $cookie
    ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $result = json_decode($response);
    return response()->json($result);
}
```